# Trying to make a single-linked list in C++ that stores values in chronological order instead of storing everything backwards

Tags: c++, linked-list

I've been working for hours trying to get this program to insert values into new nodes or "Player" structures for this program.

The thing is, this takes place inside function main(). My teacher requires me to insert as little code as possible since essentially "everything" is there which allows me to change it.

Here's the original code that stores each new value in the head while putting the older value inside "addNew":

```
Player * head = NULL;

for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
{
    Player * addNew = (Player *)malloc(sizeof(Player));
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        head->len = i;

        Player * addNew = (Player *)malloc(sizeof(Player));

        head->next = NULL;
    }

    addNew->next = addNew;
    addNew->len = i;
}

Player * p = head;
//do this until 'p' has no address.
for(int i=0; p!=0; i++)
{
    printf("%s ", p->str);
    p = p->next;
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this? 
IMPORTANT: My teacher would like me to not add any new variables or a tail. Please don't ask.

Update: Here's some older code:

```
//The head is the last one to hold a value. Therefore it gets pushed to the right.
    Player * head = NULL;

    Original Algorithm
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        Player * addNew = (Player *)malloc(sizeof(Player));
        printf("Insert a string: ");
        scanf("%s", addNew->str);

        addNew->next = head; //assign head's current address to addNew->next
        head = addNew; //assign all of addNew to head       
    }
```

Update: Here's a new implementation which doesn't work. I can't really find out where exactly that other for loop should go.

```
addNew->ID = 1;
        addNew->ID += i;
        if(head == NULL)
        { 
            head = addNew;
            addNew->next = head; //assign head's current address to addNew->next
            //head->next = addNew;
        }

        //head->next = addNew;  
        addNew->next = head;
        //head = addNew; //assign all of addNew to head     
        printf("%d\n", addNew->ID);
```

Comment: Okay, so you can't use tail. What other limitations are there? And what requirements? The obvious solution would be to walk through the list on every insert, which would be disastrous in terms of performance.

Comment: So your teacher wants you to solve the problem, but not with any sane solutions. Nice. Also, that's not C++, those mallocs are begging for horrific leaks. Looks to me like your teacher wants you to learn C.

Answer (score 1):

Simple trick: have the list* always point to the last element in the list.  And set that last element's next pointer to the start of the list.  Now you can always easily find both the start and the end of the list with just one pointer.  The start is at list->next.  Don't call it tail, just "list".

Comment: I believe I can't have another pointer to a struct, unless you mean possibly renaming addNew to list.

Comment: There is no additional pointer. The idea is to rename "head" to "tail" and treat it like the tail pointer, i.e. you store the pointer to the last element. BUT instead of having the last element's next pointer point to NULL, it will point to the FIRST element (i.e. "head"). That way, you add to the end, but you can iterate from the head. Obviously, you need to stop when you reach the last element again. Hans, that's the idea, right?

Comment: Sometimes I wish I could upvote an answer more than once. I'm a sucker for these little tricks.

Comment: @Ebo: Do you mean tail->next = head?

Comment: Well, here's what I have, and it sure doesn't work the way it should. All it does is display 1.                                                  addNew->ID = 1;
  addNew->ID += i;
  if(head == NULL)
  { 
   head = addNew;
   addNew->next = head; //assign head's current address to addNew->next
   //head->next = addNew;
  }
  
  //head->next = addNew; 
  addNew->next = head;
  //head = addNew; //assign all of addNew to head  
  printf("%d\n", addNew->ID);

Answer (score 0):

You could save a pointer to the tail of the list and instead of saving the next item on each node, save the previous one.

Comment: Well, yeah, or you can just give the answer away :P You'll need to store head AND tail though, or else you won't be able to walk through the list.

Comment: True. Guess that wasn't clear at all because of the "(instead of head)" let me change that.

Comment: Unfortunately, my teacher specified that I can't use anything like "tail," which helps to make this assignment frustrating.

Comment: Well, if you can't use tail you'll have to find a way to add it at the end of the current list through means of a for/while.

Comment: I already have a for loop. I can't fathom how and where another one might be useful at all.

Comment: You have a for loop to insert n elements. You need another one inside that to insert them at the end of the list (thus iterating over all elements) rather than adding them at the beggining.

Comment: The last element I can really think of is 'head->next' or 'addNew->next'. But no matter what I do, I can't get it to store the next variable properly in the next open spot.

Comment: head->next just gives you the next item on the list. However, if you do that repeatedly, you'll end up at the last element of the list (that whose next equals null). You can then insert the new element after this one thus reversing the order of the list. However you'd have to do this for each and  every element you add to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you're adding everything to the head of the list. However, you want to add to the tail instead.

You already have a pointer to the head. In addition to that though, you'll also need a pointer to the tail. Can you think of a way to get (and update) it?

Comment: I keep saying that I can't have a tail. I'm trying to use addNew to add to the end.

Comment: Well, you kept saying that long after I posted this answer. You should have made your requirements clear in your question to begin with. In any case, Hans has a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be an option but I thought I'd suggest it anyway. Instead of storing things in a different order, you could leave things stored as they are, but simply change the way you output the values. This would not only be very simple to implement, it would also be a faster during list inserts.

Comment: As easily as I could do that(if I knew how), my teacher requires me to change how I store values.